# accessing local variable in nested block in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a scenario

```
func1 do 
  x='abc'
  func2 do
    puts x
  end
end
```

for this I get x = nil. Why is it so, and how to access external variable like x in inner block.

Comment: What is `func2`? It depends on that. If it is an iterator, `x` should not return `nil`.

Comment: sawa is right. For example, this: `Object.new.tap { x='abc'; [Object.new].each { puts x } }` outputs `abc`.

Comment: func1 & func2  are originate  &   record  function of http://rubydoc.info/gems/adhearsion/frames. x is locally defined

Answer (score 1):

You will get "abc" only if func1 and func2 executes blocks you are passing to them (yielding or calling).

Check out an example

```
def func1
end

def func2
end

func1 do
  x = "Hello World"
  func2 do
    puts x
  end
end
#=> nil

def func3
  yield
end

def func4
  yield
end

func3 do
  x = "Hello World"
  func4 do
    puts x
  end
end
#=> Hello World
```